# hook script in git is not working properly even after reverted the changes

Tags: python, shell, github, github-api

I used below pre-receive script for blocking the developers from committing the secrets insides the files.

followed the below steps to set up this in GitHub Enterprise Appliance.

1) created a repo in github, cloned to local desktop. saved the copied script (https://github.com/github/platform-samples/blob/master/pre-receive-hooks/block_confidentials.sh ) from the site as .sh file and committed and pushed.

2) in GitHub as site admin , created a hook from admincenter and pointed to previously created hookscriptone.

and after that i tested a scenario wit creating a new repo and adding a example.conf file to this.

1) When i did first commit with the simple content (without any secrets), its allowed me to commit .

2) in second scenario, i committed with a keyword "CONFIDENTIAL" in it, but it blocked as expected.

3) so for confirming the hooks functionality, i removed the "Confidential" word and tried to commit back.. but its still not allowing me to commit.

Any helps pls...